# How can I build a Trap function with any key

Tags: linux, bash, shell

This function exits my script when I press cntr+C, how can i modify it to make it works when I press enter?

```
trap ctrl_c INT

function ctrl_c(){
    clear
    echo -e "\n${red}[!] Saliendo...\n${end}"
    rm *.txt 2>/dev/null
    tput cnorm; exit 1
}
```

Comment: You can't. You can only trap signals; pressing enter doesn't send a signal. There's a few other combinations you can trap though, e.g. ctrl+z.

Comment: @L3viathan okay, thanks. And if I want to use it with cntr+m for example, what should I change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might help:

```
#!/bin/bash

# map Return/Enter/Ctrl+m in your terminal to interrupt signal
stty intr ^M 

ctrl_c(){ echo 'Someone pressed Return/Enter/Ctrl+m.'; }

# Restore the default at the end of the program
back2default(){ stty intr ^C; }

trap ctrl_c INT
trap back2default EXIT

# A placeholder for more meaningful code
sleep 10
```